# Get parent div from child div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have below structure

```
<div class="A">
    <div title="Sales"></div>
</div>
```

Class A is common and present at many places on page hence i am not able to select appropriate div with class A.

I have child div with title "sales" or anything else unique at each places, I am able to get that child div with below code
`div[title='Sales']{ background-color:skyblue; }`

Now i want to select its parent div from above child div to apply background color to entire parent div
Please help

Comment: "Class A is common and present at many places on page hence i am not able to select appropriate div with class A" Why not? Just use the parent elements to make the selector more specific: `#container .foo:nth-child(2) .A` for example. We need a much more clearer example of your HTML, including the parents, in order to help you most effectively.

Comment: You want to choose parent in what language. Javascript, jQuery, CSS...? As there are many tags.

Comment: Do we need to click on the div `sale` and apply the style to `A`?

Comment: I am using this in SharePoint and i have added Modernscript editor on page so i can use CSS, JQuery or Javascript. Preferred is CSS

Comment: Did you mean that? - `$("div[title='Sales']").parents(".A").addClass('here_color_background');`

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov, I want to apply background color to entire A tag which is associated with Sales,

Then there will another A with Products child div will have different color, Products is class similar to Sales

Comment: see my example above. Is that so necessary?

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov, Yes similar to this $("div[title='Sales']").parents(".A").addClass('here_color_background');
only i want to add css directly instead of addClass.
Please let me know how this work and i am new to this

Comment: @Vishal Tanawade, Gave the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't solve this like my snippet. We probably solve em with css not js. you are using parent in your js which makes your codes more and even there's no logic for doing this why we do hard thinks?!

```html
<div class="A Sales">
    <div title="Sales"></div>
</div>

<div class="A Products">
    <div title="Sales"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As there are many tags in your question:

Jquery:

`$("div[title='Sales']").parent()`

or, better, with a filter on which parent:

`$("div[title='Sales']").parents(".A")`

in vanilla JS:

`document.querySelectorAll("div[title='Sales']").parentNode`

or

`document.querySelectorAll("div[title='Sales']").parentElement`

With CSS is currently not possible to select an element based on the child properties, but there are other ways to implement this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you can't access the parent div given a specific child element but you could fake this behaviour by adding a `box-shadow` to the child element, e.g.

```css
.A {
  border: 1px lightblue dashed;
  padding: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

[title="Sales"] {
  border: 1px yellowgreen dashed;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmax skyblue; /* or a higher value */
}
```

```html
<div class="A">
    <div title="Sales">Sales</div>
</div>
```

The hidden overflow applied to the parent will clip the area of the shadow.

Comment: This is working for me, Is there any way to reduce the size of my parent div.